# Problem with rewrite for custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides, configuration, url-rewrite

I have created a module to disable user registration (mostly following guide here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959131/how-to-disable-frontend-registration-in-magento/25186894).

Unfortunately, I have a strange problem in that the rewrite works if the url is "/customer/account/create" but not if it is "/customer/account/create/" - the trailing slash causes strange behaviour, in that not only is the registration form loaded, but also a 404.

My config.xml consists of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_DisableRegistration>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_DisableRegistration>
</modules>
<global>
    <rewrite>
         <company_disableregistration_customer_account_create>
                  <from><![CDATA[#^/?customer/account/create/#]]></from>
                  <to>/disableregistration/customer_account/create</to>
             </company_disableregistration_customer_account_create>
             <company_disableregistration_customer_account_createPost>
                 <from><![CDATA[#^/?customer/account/createPost/#]]></from>
                 <to>/disableregistration/customer_account/createPost</to>
             </company_disableregistration_customer_account_createPost>
       </rewrite> 
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_DisableRegistration before="Mage_Customer">Company_DisableRegistration_Customer</Company_DisableRegistration>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

This is the first time I've attempted this sort of thing, so I'm not sure what the issue is or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by amending the config.xml as follows (essentially, removing the global rewrites entirely):

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Reckless_DisableRegistration>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Reckless_DisableRegistration>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Reckless_DisableRegistration before="Mage_Customer">Reckless_DisableRegistration_Customer</Reckless_DisableRegistration>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

I would be interested to have my solution further explained to me - does anyone have a link to a resource explaining this syntax in detail?

Answer (score 2):

I normally use something like

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/$#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/$1]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

See $# in the end of the original URL and also the complete node.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I thought the $ was if part of the url was dynamic (for instance with id). But I tried to add as example and also added teh complete node. Now it no longer shows the register form, however it just 404s - rather than be routed to my custom handler (again, without trailing slash, my custom handler is called). Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, try putting both urls wrapped in CDATA.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue with  your controller rewrite code

**from**

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
         <company_disableregistration_customer_account_create>
                  <from><![CDATA[#^/?customer/account/create/#]]></from>
                  <to>/disableregistration/customer_account/create</to>
             </company_disableregistration_customer_account_create>
             <company_disableregistration_customer_account_createPost>
                 <from><![CDATA[#^/?customer/account/createPost/#]]></from>
                 <to>/disableregistration/customer_account/createPost</to>
             </company_disableregistration_customer_account_createPost>
       </rewrite> 
</global>
```

**to**

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
         <company_disableregistration_customer_account_create>
                  <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/create/#]]></from>
                  <to>/disableregistration/customer_account/create</to>
             </company_disableregistration_customer_account_create>
             <company_disableregistration_customer_account_createPost>
                 <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/createPost/#]]></from>
                 <to>/disableregistration/customer_account/createPost</to>
             </company_disableregistration_customer_account_createPost>
       </rewrite> 
</global>
```

As you have using magento old rewrite process ,you did not need this below code,which is used for new controller rewrite  process:

More details at :http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/

**not needed**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_DisableRegistration before="Mage_Customer">Company_DisableRegistration_Customer</Company_DisableRegistration>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

You need to define your module frontName by Using below code
**Add**
    
            
                
                    
                    standard
                    
                        Company_DisableRegistration_Customer
                        
                        disableregistration

Your `AccountController.php file location should` be `Company>DisableRegistration>Controllers>Customer>`
Accountcontroller code is

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Customer").DS."AccountController.php";
class Company_DisableRegistration_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
}
```

Comment: I tried to make the changes you suggested. But after changing the first block and removing the second, entering the url without a forward slash simply serves the standard register page, and with a slash I again get a 404 content output with the register form. I did already have the controller located as you have instructed. Any ideas?